# jsoup does not return all cookies when I login to a website

Tags: java, cookies, jsoup

I'm trying to login to a website, but my code returns only 2 cookies instead of more than 10 cookies. Here is what I'm using:

```
cookies = Jsoup.connect("https://www.e-cigarette-forum.com/forum/login")
                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.152 Safari/537.36")
                .data("login", "username")
                .data("register", "0")
                .data("password", "password")
                .data("submit", "Log in")
                .data("remember", "1")
                .data("cookie_check", "1")
                .data("_xfToken", "")
                .data("redirect", "https://www.e-cigarette-forum.com/forum/")
                .followRedirects(false)
                .method(org.jsoup.Connection.Method.POST).timeout(50000).execute().cookies();
```

When I print the cookies I got the following cookies:

> xf_session = c683e3cd72e296ec0bc8d4e36403fc1a
>
> __cfduid   = d82ccf7651e7a7cf07c102a7782476c081436435336

Does anyone know what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead:

> https://www.e-cigarette-forum.com/forum/login

You must use:

> https://www.e-cigarette-forum.com/forum/login/login

[image]

Working code:

```
try {

            String url = "https://www.e-cigarette-forum.com/forum/login/login/";

            Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect(url)
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.152 Safari/537.36")
                    .data("login", "username")
                    .data("password", "password")
                    .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                    .followRedirects(true)
                    .execute();

            Document document = response.parse();

            System.out.println("Hi " + document.select(".username.NoOverlay").html());

            Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.e-cigarette-forum.com/forum/account/personal-details")
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.152 Safari/537.36")
                    .cookies(response.cookies())
                    .followRedirects(true)
                    .get();

            System.out.println(doc);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```